# Facial Recognition in Java/Processing

Tags: java, image-processing, processing, face-detection

I am doing a project that requires some facial recognition. I am attempting to find a Java implementation of this. I am not looking for facial detection. We are trying to do facial recognition through a live camera feed.

Is there any way to implement this in Java or Processing?

At the moment the only ones I have been able to find are in some type of C, which is not going to work for me.

Answer (score 20):

I am working on the Face Detection/ Face Recognition topic as well. I can recommend the following links for Face Recognition:

Direct Java Implementations:

- [JavaFaces: A Java Implementation of Face Recognition with Eigenfaces](http://code.google.com/p/javafaces/)
- [Explanation and Refactoring of the above library](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/index.html)
- [Article Face Recognition using Eigenfaces](http://onionesquereality.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/face-recognition-using-eigenfaces-and-distance-classifiers-a-tutorial/)

Implementation with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) so you could use [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) to implement FR in Java:

- [OpenCV implementation of Face Recognition](https://etienne.membrives.fr/pebibyte/articles/simple-face-recognition-using-opencv/)

I used the first approach - using javafaces directly. If you accomplish using OpenCV/JavaCV to make FR work give me a hint please.

Cheers

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to use JavaFaces and I currently have it running on Eclipse on my Mac. But every time I run it, and choose a directory it says 'select a directory'. Does this come with a manual or something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Processing, I recommend the [OpenCV for Processing Library](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing). Easy to use and with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer:
A repository of Processing examples for ITP fall workshop about face detection, recognition, and miscellaneous tracking methods.

- [Face-It by Shiffman](https://github.com/shiffman/Face-It)

Answer (score 1):

Although quite old question but still relevant.

You can use opencv library. Although its written in C++. But it offers java bindings too. Only drawback is you will have to build java bindings yourself. [Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/facial-recognition-using-opencv-in-java-92fa40c22f62) is one article written by myself which explains the procedure to build the java bindings and sample programs for facial recognition.