# Swing Framework in Java Have Face Recognition and Voice recognition

Tags: java, swing, voice-recognition, face-recognition

Is Swing Framework in Java Have Face Recognition and Voice recognition Option/Capability/System?

(Im a new born baby in Java & Swing
Moreover I searched on net but i dont find anything helpful.Please Suggest me or Show guideline/resource)

Comment: please those hints are about,

Answer (score 3):

Swing is a GUI API/toolkit. For building user interfaces.

Recognizing faces or voices has nothing to do with building user interfaces. Perhaps this is why your searches aren't finding anything.

If you google for "Java Face Recognition" you get lots of results. e.g.
[Facial Recognition in Java/Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228732/facial-recognition-in-java-processing)

or "Java voice recognition"
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Swing is a library for rich GUI programming. There is no relationship between voice recognition and GUI.

Understanding this I googled "voice recognition library java" and here is the first result:
http://voce.sourceforge.net/
Sounds good. It is an open-source cross platform library for voice recognition that exposes C++ and Java API.

Same is about search "face recognition library java".

Good luck.